# Android: Custom listview with imageview and textview

Tags: android, user-interface, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am new to android and want to make Listview based application. In my app i have one imageview and one textview. I refer many tutorials but every time i get confused. Please provide me simple listview based tutorial. I don't understand when to use custom ArrayAdapter and how to use it.

Please suggest me the way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: For future reference when asking a question, this is how I found it "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=custom+adapter+listview+%5Bandroid%5D  and it was the second post. If you still don't understand after that then you need to post your attempt and what part you are stuck on.

Comment: First of all, you try for simple listview then you go for custom listview.